# Adding $\Theta$ notations in a recursive setting

Tags: asymptotics

I know the fact that if we have two functions $f$ and $g$ it is valid to say that:

$$ \Theta( f(n) + g(n)) = \Theta( \max\{f(n), g(n)\})$$

My question is if this is valid when $g$ is not a separate function, but also some kind of $f$?

For example, if we have:

$$f(n) = f(n-1)+f(n/3)+ f(n/9)+\dots+ f(n/3^{\log_3(n)})$$

Is it ok to say that:

$$\Theta( f(n))= \Theta(f(n-1))+\Theta(f(n/3) + f(n/9)+\dots)$$

(Note that we take theta of the first + theta of the rest)

I know adding $\Theta$s sounds weird but even some textbooks say we use this informally because this is more convenient (so disregard this non-formal writing).

Comment: If $a = b+c$ then $\Theta(a) = \Theta(b) + \Theta(c)$. This holds for all functions $a,b,c$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus So it basically holds even if it is the same recurrence function but with different "insides" (such as a sum of $f(n-1)+ f(n/5) + f(1/2^n)$ just to be sure (some extreme examples..)

Comment: It holds for all functions $a,b,c$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thank you sir!!

Comment: @CSchofx The comments above should say "all *positive* functions".

Comment: Note that if this is related to your previous question about computing the asymptotics of a recursively defined function, this still doesn't allow you to "decompose" the problem as you wanted to do. Say $f$ is defined by $f(n) = a_1f(b_1n) + a_2f(b_2n)$. Then you can't simply solve $g(n) = a_1g(b_1n)$ and $h(n) = a_2h(b_2n)$ then conclude $f(n) \in \Theta(g(n) + h(n))$.